# Regular expression AlphaNumeric comma delimited infinite times

Tags: c#, regex

I have managed to piece together this
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+,?\s*)+$

will match the following
Prek,1,12,3,4, --caveat may have spaces (bullet proofing)

however, it is including the comma as part of the string.  I am not understanding how to get the comma to not be included as part of the capture.  I tried moving it around in varies ways with the () and using extra [] but it doesn't get me the results I like.

And I know many people will say just use split, however, I am doing an automated ETL and I have regular expressions set up for a generic scenario based on state.  So I am trying to avoid if this state do this.  If that state then do this.  and would just like to loop through the expressions match them up and process them.

Comment: "*however, it is including the comma as part of the string*" - please explain what you mean by this.

Comment: When retrieving the grouping it was including the , after the alphanumeric value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general regex pattern which might fit your need is:

```regex
[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s*,\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+)*
```

Explanation:

```regex
[A-Za-z0-9]+      an initial alphanumeric term
(?:               (open non capturing group)
    \s*           optional whitespace
    ,             comma separator
    \s*           more optional whitespace
    [A-Za-z0-9]+  another alphanumeric term
)*                zero or more times (close non capturing group)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use split, you could make use of the `\G` anchor to get continuous matches, capturing  between comma's and optional whitespace chars.

```
\G([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\s*,\s*|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\G` Assert the postition at the end of the previous match, in this case at the start
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times any in the character class
- `(?:\s*,\s*|$)` Match either a comma between optional whitespace chars or assert the end of the string

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cG%28%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5cs*%2c%5cs*%7c%24%29&i=Prek%2c1%2c12%2c3%2c4%2c)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding this did not work though if you look at your screen capture you provided you see it didn't match on the prek it combined it with prek, 1

Comment: @Angela I have updated the answer to get Prek also in group 1.